# How would you test a browser?

Tags: testing, browser, automation

I have two questions about testing a browser
The browser I am trying to test is somewhat hybrid. It sometimes runs in chromium way and sometimes runs in internet explorer way

1. It's hard to check whether all the websites work well in a browser. How would you check that? If there is a good open-source automation tool to do this, would you guys recommend me?
2. If there is anyone testing a browser, how do you guys automate the test? (if there is a good scenario form, i'd be grateful if you guys share and sharing a automation tool would be nice too)

I'd appreciate it if I get a reply :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few good technologies in this realm:

1. For testing and validation of web development / websites in general you can use **Selenium Grid** which is meant to test websites in various browses
   The URL for Selenium Grid: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2
2. To automate use cases in a browser you can use the free popular **Selenium** tool which can be used in various languages (http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/). 
     Other tools:
   **Mechanize** (http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) 
   **Watir** (http://watir.com/)

Answer (score 1):

https://crossbrowsertesting.com/
http://www.multibrowserviewer.com/

you can use selenium ide tool for automation testing.